# Django Admin Page on New/Chage display objects not values

Tags: django

I am create a simple model and admin in Django.

Below is the model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = models.TextField(default="")
    text = models.TextField(default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey('cms.Category', default="")
    status = models.ForeignKey('cms.Status', default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"
```

And below the admin registration

```
Class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @staticmethod
    def get_status(obj):
        return obj.status.status

    @staticmethod
    def get_category(obj):
        return obj.category.category

    list_display = ('title', 'get_status', 'get_category')
```

Although I am getting the below, i.e. objects not values.

[Snapshot from Django Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6i9F.png)

I am trying to resolve this and I would like to know where to look for.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Mention the fields in fieldsets variable like `fieldsets=((None,{'fields':('title','get_status','get_category'),}),)`

Comment: when I add this I am getting an exception as get_status and get_category are not  specified for Article class. ???/

Comment: Create those methods in the Article model class and use @property decorator. It should work.

Comment: @georgiosn_1 why you unverified my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add a `__str__` method to your model class. You can find the documentation for [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#str) here.

So, if you wanted your django admin panel to show specific string representations of objects this how you would do it.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = models.TextField(default="")
    text = models.TextField(default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey('cms.Category', default="")
    status = models.ForeignKey('cms.Status', default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This would show Article title instead of 'Article Object 1' in your admin panel.
Hope this helps.

Comment: good guidance - actually you have to add it to the classes that you have the ForeignKey

Comment: @georgiosn_1 yes, all classes that are in your admin panel should ideally have a `__str__` method.

Answer (score 0):

in models.py add `__str__()` to `status` and `category`

```
class Status(self):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

class Category(self):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

no need to write methods into `admin.py`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback to use the `__str__` method class you have to add a function for the FK Value field. Below the example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = models.TextField(default="")
    text = models.TextField(default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey('cms.Category', default="", editable="false")
    status = models.ForeignKey('cms.Status', default="", editable="false")


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"


class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Statuses"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

and below the snapshot from the site 
[image]

Thanks a  lot!